# Sorting array by beacon streight

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, ibeacon

I have few beacons for fun. I want list them on view by strength rssi. So basically they will change place on list depend on distance receiver from beacon in a period time for example every 10 sec..
What's the better way, use sqllite and save address beacon and straight rssi, then sort them, or do this in some array?
Is there some way to sort items in array, in my example addresses of beacons depend on rssi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), you can sort the ranged beacons by RSSI with code like this:

```
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    ArrayList<Beacon> sortedBeacons = new ArrayList<Beacon>(beacons);
    Collections.sort(sortedBeacons, new Comparator<Beacon>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Beacon beacon0, Beacon beacon1) {
            return new Integer(beacon0.getRssi()).compareTo(new Integer(beacon1.getRssi()));
        }

    });

    // Add code here to update display with sortedBeacons
}
```

Comment: I use Android Beacon Lib but in your example I don't know why in sortedBeacons there's always only one beacon?

Comment: If there is only one beacon in the `sortedBeacons` `ArrayList`  then that means there is only one beacon in the beacons collection passed in to the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` method.  This suggests that you only have one beacon visible that matches your defined `Region.`

Comment: OK I think i figure out what's wrong. My beacons has only different name(string) so in array he shows only one position I don't know why? Every beacon has different mac address. When I change Minor value in every beacon they show up. But sorting doesn't work property. My plan was have beacons with different names and rest values the same. Is it possible or every beacon must have different Minor or Major value to get sorting?

Comment: In version 2.3 an higher of the Android Beacon LIbrary, you can set `Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true);` which will cause advertisements with distinct mac addresses to be treated as different beacons.  If you do not set this, the default behavior is for two hardware devices transmitting the same identifiers to be treated as a single beacon.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array as the data is pretty short lived so the database overhead is not worth it. Then use `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` where the `Comparator` compares the single strengths. To run every 10 seconds use `Handler`'s `postDelayed`.